# node_modules not available in image when running in OpenShift

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, openshift, node-modules

I have a Dockerfile for a NodeJS project where I do a `npm i` against a `package.json`. The `docker build` goes through fine. I can confirm that the `node_modules` folder is indeed available at the required location when I inspect the image with [`dive`](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive). Further, I can run the image successfully locally with `docker run -it imageName -p 1880:1880`.

However, this image does not run in OpenShift as the `js` file required by `npm start` is not available because `node_modules` is missing. I added a command in the `Deployment` YAML for `sleep infinity` to look into the file system for myself. Indeed, the `node_modules` folder is missing. Further, if I did a `npm i` *in the container*, the installation goes through and so does `npm start`.

I don't get why `node_modules` is not visible when running the image in OpenShift!

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# Copy scripts see - https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/tree/master/docker-custom/scripts
COPY scripts/*.sh /tmp/

# Install tools, create Node-RED app, add user and set rights
RUN set -ex && \
    apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        tzdata \
        iputils \
        curl \
        nano \
        git \
        openssl \
        openssh-client && \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/node-red && \
    deluser --remove-home node && \
    adduser -h /usr/src/node-red -D -H node-red -u 1000 && \
    chown -R node-red:root /usr/src/node-red && chmod -R g+rwX /usr/src/node-red

# Install Build tools
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual buildtools build-base linux-headers udev python && \
    /tmp/remove_native_gpio.sh && \
    /tmp/install_devtools.sh && \
    rm -r /tmp/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/node-red

# package.json - https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/blob/master/docker-custom/package.json
COPY package.json .
COPY flows.json .
COPY flows_cred.json .
# https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/settings-file
COPY settings.js .

RUN chown -R node-red:root /usr/src/node-red

USER node-red

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 1880

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start", "--userDir", "/usr/src/node-red", "--settings", "/usr/src/node-red/settings.js"]
```

### Deployment YAML

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-red-ui
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-red-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-red-ui
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: node-red-ui
        image: repo/imageName:tag
        env:
          - name: NODE_RED_VERSION
            value: 1.0.3
          - name: NODE_PATH
            value: /usr/src/node-red/node_modules
          - name: HOME
            value: /usr/src/node-red
          - name: FLOWS
            value: flows.json
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
          name: ui-port
      imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: If you can run the image locally with no `docker run -e` options, I'd be suspicious of the environment variable settings causing trouble (especially `$NODE_PATH`).  Does deleting the entire `env:` section from the pod spec improve things?

Comment: No effect with `env` section removed. BTW, I also tried with `-e` for `docker run` - this works.

Comment: Can you post the `env` output from `docker run` command and as well as `env` from the POD deployment.

Comment: Not sure if your Deployment definition here is complete, do you mount any volumes in your `Deployment`? If you mount an emptyDir into your container, that could explain the empty folder